# How to handle the fIxed length(2712) related issue in UNIQUE key constraint in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE m_value
(
  handle character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  field_id integer,
  value text,
  CONSTRAINT m_value_handle_field_id_value_key UNIQUE (handle, metadata_field_id, metadata_value)
)
```

Now when I am trying to insert values, in some cases it is throwing error

> ERROR: index row size 3072 exceeds maximum 2712 for index
>   "m_value_handle_field_id_value_key"

According to my understanding, when the total string size of the three fields [**handle,field_id and value**] is getting larger than 2712, it is throwing error. Is it possible to define this unique constraint in any other way? I need to define unique key in composition of this three fields. Please help!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25140/30035

Comment: `metadata_value` must be a big value - you can `md5(metadata_value)` it for example...

Comment: Do i have to create a index like : 
`CREATE INDEX m_value_handle_field_id_value_key ON m_value(handle, metadata_field_id, md5(metadata_value));`

Comment: aha, I would give it a try - anyway index cant be bigger then 1/3 of a page. so maybe you would be able to build it with bigger page and the have  a longer index "row", but it definetely does not look a good idea